# MPAndroidChart is there a way to remove all number indication?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have implemented MPAndroidChart in my app, i would to be able to view the line graph only, with no numbers, labels or indications, is the any way to do that?
@PhilJay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

As for the x- and y-axis, simply disable them by calling:

- `axis.setEnabled(false)`

As for the numbers inside the chart, simply call

- `lineData.setDrawValues(false)`

on your `LineData` object.

All that can also be found in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki) about the `XAxis`, `YAxis` and the `ChartData` object.

Comment: Thank you very much!! i have missed it in the doc, in this part:
"setEnabled(boolean enabled): Sets the axis enabled or disabled. If disabled, no part of the axis will be drawn"
I did not realize it refers to the numbers a s well.

thank you!

Comment: If you want, you can also only prevent the axis values from not being drawn, and not the whole axis. It's also in the documentation.

Comment: I see now, Thank you very much sir, this is a great library.